# Crossword clue “Trouble follows loud bomb”

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

Please explain this clue:

> Trouble follows loud bomb

The answer given is:

> fail

Comment: Where did you get this clue from?

Answer (score 10):

> Trouble is "ail, and loud is "F" (the musical annotation for "forte").
>
>  Putting them together you have "ail" following "F" to give you "fail".
>
>  And bomb is the definition (in the sense of a play or film bombing (failing)).

Comment: The "loud bomb" was a nice distraction!